# Javascript Data Format, Is This JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Some jquery plugins I use require a data of this format as its input type

```
[
{image : '1.jpg', title : 'Title', url : '', age : 24, location : 'US', name : 'John', description : 'Long Text'},  
{image : '1.jpg', title : 'Title', url : '', age : 24, location : 'US', name : 'John', description : 'Long Text'}, 
{image : '1.jpg', title : 'Title', url : '', age : 24, location : 'US', name : 'John', description : 'Long Text'}
]
```

My question is, what is this kind of data and how to create it? Is this still JSON? because when I try to pass json_encoded array with PHP and get it with jquery, I get this format :

```
[
{'image' : '1.jpg', 'title' : 'Title', 'url' : '', 'age' : 24, 'location' : 'US', 'name' : 'John', 'description' : 'Long Text'},  
{'image' : '1.jpg', 'title' : 'Title', 'url' : '', 'age' : 24, 'location' : 'US', 'name' : 'John', 'description' : 'Long Text'}, 
{'image' : '1.jpg', 'title' : 'Title', 'url' : '', 'age' : 24, 'location' : 'US', 'name' : 'John', 'description' : 'Long Text'}
]
```

Notice the quotes that wrap the variable name. That makes the code not working.

Comment: which jquert plug in is that?

Comment: actually my question hasn't been answered. that's why i still haven't accepted yet.

Comment: the first one is an associative array, inside another array. associative array are also Objects,"JSON"

Comment: did you get this sorted out Henson?

Comment: actually not yet, but this plugin has been chalked off of my project, so i don't really need it for now. but it'll be a good one if anyone can answers though. supersized just needs this to be perfect.

Answer (score 5):

The first is a JavaScript **array literal** which contains **object literals**. *It is [**not** JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).*

The second is also an array literal that contains objects. It's *closer* to [JSON](http://json.org), but is not 100% valid, since JSON requires that **all strings are double-quoted.** For example, this is valid JSON:

```
[{"image": "1.jpg", "title": "Title" }]
```

---

If you're unsure if you're looking at valid JSON, you can always run it through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and see for yourself.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. It's an object literal. You "create" it by typing it out, just like you "create" a string literal by typing `"foo"`, or "create" a number literal by typing `123.4`. [This MDC article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Literals) might be useful to you.

Comment: i think i get it. what i'm looking for is actually a way to create object literal the same way i create JSON (you know, associative arrays + json_encode php function). i guess there's no other way than looping through the data and typing image : 'some_url', etc right?

Comment: You want to do this in PHP, right? JSON is the right interchange format to use. The quoted keys are almost certainly not the cause of the problem when using JSON instead of an object literal. Are you actually parsing the JSON when you get it with jQuery? What jQuery function were you using to get the JSON that was having issues with quoted keys?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't appear that the plugins are requiring JSON - looks more like a dictionary of some kind.

Valid JSON looks something similar to: {"name":"John", "age":50}

You will probably need to build a custom helper method to format the data correctly for your plugins, can give you a hand if you provide a bit more of your source code :)

Comment: actually i think the plugin doesn't mention JSON (the plugin is jquery supersized). so how can I create the format? i haven't coded it to php yet, that's just static page (the image data is hardcoded in the js file). That's why i want to make it dynamic by using php and use jquery to get the php content, just need a way to create the format

Comment: There's a couple of ways you could do it. First would be to create the template as a string on the server side, generate your dynamic data, replace where appropriate in your template then finally embed the generated string in your jQuery. Second option would be to create a web method jQuery can call which returns the data to the as an array or list then let jQuery create the objects from the this. Hope that makes sense, if not let me know and I'll try and explain better - Tim

Comment: sorry tim but can you explain more? To generate json, I can create an associative array and use php json_encode function to prepare the data for jquery. but the thing is, with json the result will be like the second code I posted above (with the double quotes though), which cannot be recognized by supersized. while my desired format is the first one. and i think i've tried and failed, in php we can't do $array[name] = "Joe", i mean the associative array requires the key to be a string or number, CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to put this is another answer so it's easier to read...

In this instance you don't want to generate JSON, the plugin requires a literal array as Matt Ball said.

Basic code format will be something similar to this (will be semi .NET sorry...):

```
public Array GenerateData()
{
// Generate dynamic data here and return as a list / array
}

// Get the data
Array dynamicData = GenerateData();

// Create the template
string template = "[";

// For each item in list, add to the template
foreach (item in dynamicData)
{
    template += "{ image : '" + item[0] + "', title : '" + item[1] + "', url : '" + item[2] + "', age : " + item[3] + ", location : '" + item[4] + "', name : '" + item[5] + "', description : '" + item[6] + "' },"
}

// Add closing brack - may need to trim off last comma also?
string template = "]";
```

Then embed the template string in your plug intitialisation.